# GDB and GCC union

Tags: c++

My concept may sound a bit cryptic but I what some startup information as to how we can use GDB APIs / debugging techniques in programs with GCC when we compile the program. We can definitely tell gcc to link GDB libs also. The ultimate aid would be that when the compiled programs executes it should produce logs in following format:

filename.cpp:linenumber

Is there any way we can achieve it - I do believe it is cause how would GDB knows these details and I looking for some knowhow’s to begin with.

Comment: Where in the code do you want to write the logs?  Can you just edit the source code and insert calls into a logging macro?

Comment: That would be a more manual tedious approach to add in each source code file in a project. How does GDB knows the source listing / traces etc - but my requirement is just source listing that also which function / line. If we can add a GDB API when the program starts up and be able to print the function / line of code - is that possible

Comment: When do you want to print out the line number information?  Every time a function starts or stops?

Comment: A function can span across 100 of code lines with some being conditional, iterative etc - it is not madatory to print file:function:linenumber when execution enters / exits code - as long as what code it execute is the concern

Comment: @Sanjay: When do you want to print out this information?  Do you want to be able to attach to the program and see what it is executing then?

Comment: It should be by default - after compilation when anyone starts the execution, then based upon scenarios when any flow is picked up - the logging should be automatic. As such there would not be usage of gdb or any other tool to debug the flow. This log would be the highly beneficial for our projects to analyze the issue within no time

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested in the comments, one of the options is to use a macro like the one below:

```
#define TRACE(_lvl, _msg) \
    if ( IsTraceActive() && _lvl <= TraceActiveLevel() ) { \
        std::ostringstream _trc_sstr; \
        _trc_sstr << _msg; \
        TraceWrite(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__, _trc_sstr.str()); \
    }\
```

If you are using C++, you can combine it with a class, which writes a log when entering or exiting a function (in ctor and dtor) and with backtrace (http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6391).

```
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <cxxabi.h>

class TraceFunc {
public:
    TraceFunc(const char* fnc, const char* file, int line)
    : _fnc(fnc), _file(file), _line(line)
    {
        TraceWrite(_fnc, _file, _line, std::string(_fnc) + " in");
    }


    virtual ~TraceFnc()
    {
        TraceWrite(_fnc, m_file, _line, std::string(_fnc) + " out");
    }

private:
    const char* _fnc;
    const char* _file;
    int         _line;
};

#define FNTRACE() TraceFunc _this_fnc(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__)

typedef std::vector<std::string> Stack;

Stack GetExecutionStack(int a_maxDepth)
{
    Stack stack;

    const int c_maxFuncName(500);

    void *trace[c_maxDepth+1];
    char **symbols(NULL);
    char fname[c_maxFuncName];
    int traceSize(0);

    traceSize = backtrace(trace, a_maxDepth+1);
    symbols = backtrace_symbols(trace, traceSize);

    if (symbols == NULL) {
        return stack;
    }

    // Starting at 1 to skip the function that we are currently in
    for (int i = 1; i < traceSize; ++i) {
        Dl_info info;
        if (dladdr(trace[i], &info) != 0) {
            int stat;
            char *demangled = abi::__cxa_demangle(info.dli_sname, 0, 0, &stat);

            if (demangled != NULL) {
                // Re-compose the stack info with de-mangled C++ name
                snprintf(fname, c_maxFuncName, "%s(%s) [0x%p]",
                    info.dli_fname, demangled, info.dli_saddr);
                stack.push_back(fname);
                free(demangled);
            }
            else {
                stack.push_back(std::string(symbols[i]));
            }
        }
        else {
            stack.push_back(std::string(symbols[i]));
        }
    }

    free(symbols);
    return stack;
}
```

It is used like this:

```
int MySpecialFunc()
{
    FNTRACE();

    // Some code

    TRACE(1, "Intermediate value: " << z << " mm.");

    // more code
}
```